# Cannot drop 'local' database while replication is active

Tags: mongodb

I've rs.remove(secondary) from the primary server, now going back to that secondary i want to delete all the data so i can set it up with a other primary, so i've deleted the /var/lib/mongodb, now going back to check if everything is deleted, i can only find local db with

```
replset.minvalid
replset.oplogTruncateAfterPoint
startup_log
system.rollback.id
```

so when i db.dropDatabase()
i get the following

```
"operationTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Cannot drop 'local' database while replication is active",
    "code" : 20,
    "codeName" : "IllegalOperation",
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
```

what is wrong ?

Answer (score 5):

Your command line or config file still have the `replSet` parameter in it, so replication is still active.

Check for lingering [replication options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#replication-options) in your config file, or the [`--replSet` parameter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/index.html#cmdoption-mongod-replset) in the `mongod` executable.